# MFP CLI 7.1 adapter wont deploy with mfp push command

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I have my project on github https://github.com/drkhannah/KMF

I pushed this MFP cli 7.1 project to github and had a team member clone it

After an npm install, I tried the 'mfp cordova preview' command, errors said this wasnt an mfp project, then I tried 'cordova platform add ios and android', then 'mfp cordova preview' worked, is this only because the platforms folder was in the .gitignore?

Also I had trouble adding an adapter, since I uploaded to github without adapters, the adapters folder was empty, so git didn't track it, not till I added an adapters folder in my mfp project folder(server) could I get 'mfp adapter add' to work, but now 'mfp push' deploy the adapter, it only deploys the cordova app

Why is this happening?

Comment: I fixed this, I had to do mfp deploy from the mfp project folder, mfp push wasn't pushing the adapter, but mfp deploy did

Comment: Please write this as an answer rather than a comment. Also feel free to open a PMR so that the development team will investigate why a deprecated command worked (mfp deploy) and not the command you are supposed to use (mfp push).

Comment: Hi @DerekHannah, I also have problems runnung `mfp adapter add` in my cordova project. What did you do to resolve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this, I had to do mfp deploy from the mfp project folder, mfp push wasn't pushing the adapter, but mfp deploy did