# IBM MobileFirst Platform (mfp) CLI 7.1 Adapter won't deploy with mfp push command

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-cli

Same as this issue: [MFP CLI 7.1 adapter wont deploy with mfp push command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652916/mfp-cli-7-1-adapter-wont-deploy-with-mfp-push-command#)

But the stated solution of running mfp deploy is not the best solution I think.

Running mfp deploy DOES technically work, but it is deprecated.

Why does mfp push not push my adapters?

In my case, I have a cordova project (CordovaTest). Inside that project I have created my mobilefirst runtime that I made with mfp create (CordovaTestMobileFirst). Inside that runtime I have created my adapter (CordovaTestAdapter). Running mfp push outputs the following:

```
c:\ecomproj\CordovaTest\CordovaTestMobileFirst\adapters\CordovaTestAdapter>mfp push
Preparing for push...
Verifying Server Configuration...
Runtime 'CordovaTestMobileFirst' will be used to push the project into.
Embedded Cordova Command: cordova prepare android
Embedded Cordova Command: cordova prepare ios
Pushing to Server...
Deploying c:\ecomproj\CordovaTest\mobilefirst\com_ibm_CordovaTest-android-1.0.0.wlapp...
Deploy complete for c:\ecomproj\CordovaTest\mobilefirst\com_ibm_CordovaTest-android-1.0.0.wlapp.
Deploying c:\ecomproj\CordovaTest\mobilefirst\com_ibm_CordovaTest-iphone-1.0.0.wlapp...
Deploy complete for c:\ecomproj\CordovaTest\mobilefirst\com_ibm_CordovaTest-iphone-1.0.0.wlapp.
c:\ecomproj\CordovaTest\mobilefirst\com_ibm_CordovaTest-android-1.0.0.wlapp has been deployed.
c:\ecomproj\CordovaTest\mobilefirst\com_ibm_CordovaTest-iphone-1.0.0.wlapp has been deployed.
Push Completed Successfully.
```

At this point, the adapter is not deployed. I must run mfp deploy in order for the adapter to deploy.

Regarding the above output, I expect that running mfp push from the adapters/CordovaTestAdapter directory would only build and deploy the adapter, not the entire project. It seems to behave as though I were in the root project folder. It builds and pushes the Cordova project anyway.

I've created a runtime without cordova, and added an adapter to it. When I ran mfp push from the runtime's root directory, it pushes the adapter successfully. Seems like this issue only exists for runtimes inside a Cordova project.

```
c:\ecomproj\MobileFirstTest2>mfp push
Preparing for push...
Verifying Server Configuration...
Runtime 'MobileFirstTest2' will be used to push the project into.
Pushing to Server...
Deploying c:\ecomproj\MobileFirstTest2\bin\MobileFirstTest2Adapter.adapter...
Deploy complete for c:\ecomproj\MobileFirstTest2\bin\MobileFirstTest2Adapter.adapter.
c:\ecomproj\MobileFirstTest2\bin\MobileFirstTest2Adapter.adapter has been deployed.
Push Completed Successfully.
```

Comment: In the first instance, if you run "mfp push" from the root of the project "c:\ecomproj\CordovaTest\CordovaTestMobileFirst" , does it deploy adapter as well ( along with other artifacts)?

Comment: No, it does the same thing whether I run at cordova root, mobilefirst runtime root, or in the adapter directory. Adapters are never deployed. Thanks.